# How to align an image and contact info in the same line, using inline css for an email newsletter

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to align an image and some text next to the image for an email newsletter. I used align left to try and get the image and words to align correctly.When i look at the code in the browser it looks like its supposed to. When i copy the code and past it into outlook the words are all on top of each other, and not neatly vertically aligned.  I would like to have the image on the left and the text vertically aligned to the right of the image.

code:

```
    <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#4A9FE8" style="padding: 0px;line-height: 6pt;" align="left">
                <img src="=" alt=""
                    width="15%" align="left" style="margin: 5px;">

                <h2>random guy</h2>
                <p>555.555.555 </p>
                <a href="mailto:email@email.com" style="color: black;"> email@email.com</a>
                <button style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 20px;"><a href="https://"
                        style="color: black; text-decoration: none;">My
                        Listing</a></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Different email systems implement some CSS properties which others don't. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex claims that Outlook on Windows does not support flex, and many more email systems do not support flex-direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables will do this for you by default.  Place your image and text into separate cells.

```html
<table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#4A9FE8" style="padding: 6pt ; background-color: #4A9FE8;">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" alt="" height="100" width="100">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <h2>random guy</h2>
      <p>555.555.555 </p>
      <a href="mailto:email@email.com" style="color: black;"> email@email.com</a>
      <br>
      <button style="margin: 20px">
        <a href="https://" style="color: black; text-decoration: none;">My Listing</a>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```